# Web API Put - Parameter passed is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, put

I'm using Postman to test a PUT Web API method I have written, but no matter what I try the strongly typed parameter I pass (MyModel) is always null.

**Controller Action**

```
[Route("api/myapiname/{id}/{name}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, string name, MyModel mymodel)
{
  *//Do stuff*
}
```

**MyModel Class**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel() { }

    private Boolean _b;
    public Boolean b { set { _b = value; } get { return _b; } }

    private String _comments;
    public String comments { set { _comments = value; } get { return _comments;              }}
}
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost:37781/api/myapiname/123456/laura
```

**Postman**

```
PUT: URL above

Headers: 
Content-Type: application/json

Body:
{
"MyModel":[{"b": true,"comments": "Comments go here"}]
}
```

I have tried changing this line:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, string name, MyModel mymodel)
```

to

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, string name, [FromBody]MyModel mymodel)
```

and changing the content-type on Postman to x-www-form-urlencoded and I've also tried changing the content passed to:
    =[{"b": true,"comments": "Comments go here"}]

I've tried the various solutions offered on StackOverflow but nothing I try is working, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Postman request is showing an object with an array property in the body or the request when the action is expecting a single `MyModel` object.

Here is a raw snippet of a request that matches your example action:

```
PUT /api/myapiname/123456/laura HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:37781
Content-Type: application/json
... 
Content-Length: 42

{"b": true,"comments": "Comments go here"}
```

This action:

```
[Route("api/myapiname/{id}/{name}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, string name, MyModel mymodel){...}
```

should work with the above request.

**Note**:

> To force Web API to read a **simple type** from the request body, add the
>   **[FromBody]** attribute to the parameter.

The Json in your postman request would resolve to an object like this...

```
public class MyObject {
    public MyModel[] MyModel {get; set;}
}
```

So you either need to change your request to match the action you have defined or change your action to match the request

```
[Route("api/myapiname/{id}/{name}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, string name, MyObject mymodel){...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I changed the postman request body to: {"b": true,"comments": "Comments go here"} but when I debug the code using VS the object is showing it's properties with default values/null and not the values passed from Postman.

I tried adding the [FromBody] attribute and that didn't help either.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I had an incorrect parameter name specified. It is now working, thank you very much.